# simple NE5532 preamplifier circuit troubleshooting - sound disappears at upper end of gain potentiometer

Tags: operational-amplifier, troubleshooting, preamp

I'm a bit lost trying to solve an issue I'm having with the attached microphone preamp circuit. If anyone recognizes what this problem is, I'd be very grateful for any help - thanks so much in any case!

The issue: as I turn the 50k pot the gain increases and everything seems to be working fine, but the sound disappears from when the knob is around 85% - 100% turned. When the input source is a square wave I can hear the sound of the pulse-width becoming narrower at the moment when the sound disappears. Unfortunately I don't have access to an oscilloscope, so I cannot see precisely what the output signal looks like.

Some guesses I've had were: some inaudible high frequency oscillation begins, or an issue with the power supply since +/-5v is the minimum suggested operating voltage for the NE5532.

The supply voltage is +/-5v, which is being generated from a 7805 (from a 9v DC input), then -5v is generated by an LM2662. On the multimeter these read as +4.99 and -4.98 on the NE55332's supply pins.

Here are the datasheets for the NE5532, and the LM2662:

https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1809301912_Texas-Instruments-NE5532DR_C7426.pdf

https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811041150_Texas-Instruments-LM2662MX-NOPB_C129316.pdf

[image: PCB Layout]

[image: preamp circuit]

[image: power]

Comment: quite possibly the pot itself is faulty, worn track and it goes open circuit near one end. Then the gain becomes very high, the the amp output goes to one rail or other and no AC comes out. clunK! then no sound. Do you have a multimeter?

Comment: You don't have the same resistance to ground from each input of the NE5532, the - input: 510 ohm when at highest gain but + input: 1 Mohm! See this video to learn why you might want to fix that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TxBJb-Z0XFI  The result could be that the opamp is **not** outputting 0 V DC when the gain is high and there is **no signal**. You can check that: don't apply any signal, set the gain to maximum and measure the DC voltage at the NE5532's output. Is is colde to 0 V?

Comment: Hey, @Bimpelrekkie thanks so much for the info! For your check, did you mean to leave the input floating, or to ground it? when it's floating, at power up i see -5.00V volts that slowly 0v (a capacitor somewhere is draining), after this it seems to stay at around 0v (between -.1 and .1 let's say) - when the input is ground the result seems more or less the same - is that normal?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I have noticed something else while measuring the output with no signal at the input - when I turn the pot down the output voltage swings to around +1.4v which slowly drains to 0, when I turn the pot up the voltage swings to around -2.5v that then returns to 0 - is that behavior explainable by what you were mentioning? (I'm watching the video as well, thanks so much for that!)

Comment: *did you mean to leave the input floating, or to ground it?* It does not matter much what you do as the measurement is a **DC** measurement, there is no signal involved. When you change the gain, you should **wait** until the voltage stabilizes. When you change the gain, the circuit might need to settle itself do a different DC voltage.

Comment: The **root issue** in your circuit is that your DC gain is not 1 (one, unity gain). I would have added a **capacitor** between R1, R3 and GND to make the gain at DC equal to 1. That will make sure the output of the opamp will always settle at around 0 V. I will make a drawing in an answer.

Comment: What is R6 * Ibias(IN-) * DC gain? The symptoms you describe suggest it may equal or exceed the supply voltage.

Comment: hey @user_1818839 - yes, I think this turns out to be correct - it doesn't exceed the supply voltage, but it's -3.6V (i didn't do the calculation but rather measured on the circuit as described in the answer). In addition, if I place a 510 ohm resistor in parallel with R6, the sound returns at the higher gain (DC offset is gone).

Comment: @otivlasc good experimental result. Note that the value of C2 in the accepted answer will act as a bass cut at maximum gain; if you adopt that solution, decide the LF response you want and increase C2 as necessary.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your main issue is that your amplifier has a DC gain that is much higher than 1 (one). For **audio amplifiers** you're generally concerned with frequencies between 20 Hz and 20 kHz so amplifying 0 Hz (DC) is not needed and also it creates problems!

I propose this change to make the DC gain = 1:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS93h3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The component I added is C2.

I mentioned in the comments that you don't have the same resistance to ground from the + and - inputs of the opamp. This will cause **DC offset**.

The nice thing about making the DC gain = 1 like this is that this **DC offset** will not matter much anymore! DC offset is a DC voltage, which, in your original circuit, is **amplified**.

When you add C2 like I suggest, this amplification becomes 1 (one) and therefore is doesn't matter so much anymore.

Comment: hello! I can't thank you enough for putting time into this, and for the excellent suggestions - It's a little bit difficult for me to implement this exact change to the circuit quickly because it's on a circuit board- if the issue is DC offset, is AC coupling the output with a series capacitor + resistor to ground sufficient to determine if DC offset is causing issue?

Comment: No, a series C you already have (C2), and it prevents the DC from reaching the output connector (U1). But at C2, the "damage is already done". What I would do to confirm that DC offset is the issue: short the input to GND and set the gain to max. Then measure the DC voltage at the output of the opamp and wait for the voltage to settle. Then repeat but with gain at minimum. With gain at mimimum the voltage should be much smaller.

Comment: Another way to confirm is to temporarily "hack" the circuit and change it to my proposed circuit. Instead of using **one** capacitor for R2 and R3, you can also give each resistor its own cap. Desolder R2 and solder it back on the PCB but with one side "sticking up" then solder a 1 uF cap between the R2 and the GND pad. Do the same for R3. Then try the circuit.

Comment: I understand now, before I measured the output after the AC coupling cap, not the op-amps output itself. Now that I measured the op-amps output correctly, can see that the voltage goes from -.18V to -3.60V (at the highest gain)! I will try to make the change on the circuit board next- thanks so much again!

Comment: *to -3.60V* Then the opamp will **clip**, it is likely to be the lowest output voltage it can make with a -5 V supply. When it clips, it cannot amplify anymore and you don't get a signal at the output.

Comment: Just as a test, I put a 510 ohm resistor in parallel with R6 and the sound returns at the higher gain - that also confirms that the DC offset was the issue, right? Thanks so much again for all this useful information!

Comment: *I put a 510 ohm resistor in parallel with R6* Yes, that would make the resistance to GND from + and - inputs more equal and reduce the offset. Then even when at full gain, the output of the opamp will not saturate at -3.6 V.